# i want to change the style of datatable

Tags: php, html, css, datatable

i have a datatable.its looks very bad. i want to change the style and pagination style.anybody knows please help me
am attaching the code and current view of my datatable
Now the datatable have no good style. looking very old. anybody can help me to chnage the style,then please help me
my code
index.php

```
<head>
    <link   type="text/css"  href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="css/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="css/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <form id="mytable">
        <div class="container">

            <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Minimum Date:</td>
                        <td><input name="min" id="min" type="text" class="datepicker" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Maximum Date:</td>
                        <td><input name="max" id="max" type="text" class="datepicker" ></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


            <table id="employee-grid"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
                <thead>





                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>TIME</th>
                        <th>COMPUTER NAME</th>
                        <th>USER</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>




        </div>
    </form>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: "employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource
                data :function(data){
                    data.min = $('#min').val(),
                    data.max = $('#max').val()
                }

            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "datetimes" },
                { "data": "computer_name" },
                { "data": "user" },
             ]
        });

$('#min').change(function(){
      dataTable.draw() ;
})
$('#max').change(function(){
      dataTable.draw() ;
})
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            todayHighlight: true,
            orientation: "top auto",
            todayBtn: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
        });




    });

//    
</script>
```

employeegrid.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);

/* Database connection start */
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_db";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

/* Database connection end */


// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;


$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
    0 =>'id', 
    1 => 'datetimes',
    2=> 'computer_name',
    3=> 'user'
);

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT id, datetimes, computer_name,user FROM my_table";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get my_table");

$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);

$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.


if((!empty($requestData['min'])) && (!empty($requestData['max']))){
    $minimum_date= date('Y-m-d',strtotime($requestData['min'])); 
    $maximum_date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($requestData['max'])); 
     $sql.=" where DATE(datetimes)>='".$minimum_date."' AND  DATE(datetimes)<='".$maximum_date."' ";    


}

$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get my_table");

$data = array();
$i = 0;
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array(); 
        $nestedData['id'] = $row["id"];
    $nestedData['datetimes'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row["datetimes"])); ;
    $nestedData['computer_name'] = $row["computer_name"];
    $nestedData['user'] = $row["user"];

    $data[] = $nestedData;
}



$json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
            "data"            => $data   // total data array
            );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```

[image]

Comment: You will have to pay for this dude :)

Comment: This is not a free coding service.. this is a platform for users to ask questions with regards to specific problems they might have encountered, ones they cannot solve by themselves.

Comment: "*Looks very bad*", "*looking very old*" etc. is highly opinion based.  Look at the documentation (just a wild suggestion) perhaps you can find some clues to make the dataTable look not so "old" **https://datatables.net/examples/styling/index.html**

Comment: i provided code. i didnt ask must do, asked for help @Morpheus

Comment: For a help to "change the style" ;)

Comment: if you are not like to help,then please be silent. why kidding. :p @Morpheus

Comment: go to the css file and change the styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the css selectors you should apply the styles on to your desired design.

**table header**

```
 table>thead>tr>th{
    your styling
    }
```

**pagination**

```
.dataTables_paginate{

styles
}
```

**pagination links**

```
.dataTables_paginate a {
    padding: 6px 9px !important;
    background: #ddd !important;
    border-color: #ddd !important;
}
```

if you using bootstrap you might also need to modify bootstrap.min.css line :3936

```
.pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the child elements of the table or the table's wrappers (depending on what you want to style) using the browser's Dev tool to see all classes used for the elements you wish to style and just use them in CSS. Just be careful if your project runs updates because then it will be a problem where the dataTable developers change CSS classes.

Comment: inspect the element of what exactly?

Comment: Of the table, since its what requires styling. I will edit the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

https://datatables.net/examples/styling/

I would suggest go for bootstrap 5 for a decent styling and pagination to your dataTable. Just add below dependencies in your js:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js
```

For CSS, add below links:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css
```

Sample example --> https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap5.html

You can also make changes to the table like border, shadow, background color etc. by editing jquery.dataTables.css file that contains complete set of css classes used in your dataTable. Also, make sure if you are integrating dataTables with bootstrap library, use dataTables.bootstrap.min.css instead of jquery.dataTables.css otherwise styling will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone else
I had this problem of changing the datatable styling ,resolve the issue by using the full version of dataTables.css not the minified one

- download the full dataTables.js (or just copy paste from https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.css)
- after inspecting the element that you want to change it's style , copy the class name
- search for it in the dataTables.css
- change the default style manually
- you can minify the updated file again if you want

note : i didn't search for alternative solutions i just post the solution that worked for me

Answer (score -1):

The Style of table can find it on BootStrap https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp
you can find many style for table

Comment: Unless the OP has Bootstrap in their stack (which they don't seem to have), or wants to add it, this is useless.